# Generating a system of differential equations from projectile motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that a projectile of mass $m$ moves in a vertical plane near the surface of the earth under the influence of two forces: a downward gravitational force of magnitude $mg$, and a resistive force *$\vec F_R$* that is directed opposite to the velocity vector *$\vec v$* and has magnitude $kv^2$ (where $v =$ *$|\vec v|$* is the speed of the projectile). Show that $$mx^{\prime \prime} = -kvx^{\prime}, my^{\prime \prime} = -kvy^{\prime} - mg$$ where $v = \sqrt{(x^{\prime})^2 + (y^{\prime})^2}$.

For this one I noticed that the resistive force and the force of velocity are directed along the same angle $\theta$. Thus, for the forces in the $x$ direction I have $$mx^{\prime \prime} = v \cos \theta - kv^2 \cos \theta$$ Using the fact that $\cos \theta = \frac{x^\prime}{v}$ we get $$mx^{\prime \prime} = v \cos \theta - kv^2 \cos \theta \rightarrow x^\prime - x^\prime kv$$ I still don't understand what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: There is no $vcos\theta$ term in the horizontal force component.

Comment: @Paul What do you mean?

Comment: @Paul $v \cos \theta$ is the horizontal force component of the force of velocity

Comment: $vcos\theta$ is the horizontal velocity component but that does not make it a force. The magnitude of the resistive force is $kv^2$ which has component $-kv^2cos\theta$ in the direction of the positive x axis.